# Limit of integral involving Dirac Delta

Tags: integration, limits, dirac-delta

I have to compute the following integral

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_a^\infty \delta_\epsilon (x) f(x) dx$$

where $\delta_\epsilon$(x) is such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_\epsilon (x) dx=1$, for every $\epsilon$, $f$ is an arbitrary function and

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\delta_\varepsilon(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x\neq0 \\ \infty & \text{if } x=0 \end{cases}$$

In other words, the limit of $\delta_\varepsilon$ is the delta dirac function. My guess is that the integral is given by:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_a^\infty \delta_\epsilon (x) f(x) dx = \begin{cases} f(0) & \text{if } a<0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

But I am not sure. Intuitively, it seems correct to me, but I could not find this result stated formally anywhere.

Comment: What you write is correct.

Comment: Correct, except possibly for $a=0$.  Also, instead of "arbitrary function" you need "function continuous at $0$".  And thirdly your conditions for "the dirac delta function" are sloppy:  perhaps you want not only pointwise convergence of $\delta_\epsilon$, but uniform convergence on certain sets.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, in the specific problem I am working, $\delta_\epsilon(x)=\phi(\frac{x+\epsilon}{\sqrt{2} \epsilon})$. Do you know any reference where I can find or help me prove this result?

Comment: Sorry, in the comment above, $\phi(\cdot)$ is the gaussian density.